# node-cron is not working on my server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cron, digital-ocean

So I'm using [node-cron](http://merencia.com/node-cron/) module.

I'm using this simple code and it should print **go!** everyday at 14:17.
I'm running the code in my local machine, everythings going well. But then I try to run the code on my server in DigitalOcean (Ubuntu 14), it never prints **go!** at 14:17. Nothing happen. Can you tell me what I've been missing?

```
var cron = require('node-cron');


var task = cron.schedule('0 17 14 * 1-12 0-7', function() {
  console.log('go!');
}, false);

task.start();
```

Oh, by the way I tried running another code on my server and it works, print **go!** at 0 second

```
var cron = require('node-cron');


var task = cron.schedule('0 * * * 1-12 0-7', function() {
  console.log('go!');
}, false);

task.start();
```

Comment: do your server and local machine have the same timezone set?

Comment: @elssar what command to know timezone in my ubuntu server?

Comment: run the command `date +'%z %Z` on both machines

Comment: Ah! now I know that my timezone is different between server and local machine. Thank you @elssar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your server timezone and your local timezone and see if they match.

Reconfigure your server timezone with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: ah! I just figured out that my server is EST and my local machine is WIB. I changed it and finally works fine. Thank you very much